# Generate a file from a string and send to the user C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this.

I have a DataTable being returned via stored procedure. I'm then going through it and creating a delimited file based off of the information returned.

I've made it here without any issues.

My problem is taking my StringBuilder object and creating a CSV file with it and then sending it to the user to download. I can't create a temporary file on the server due to permissions so I'm trying to do this all in memory.

I'm thinking I need to do something with a MemoryStream to create the "file" and then serving it up with Response but I'm not sure what steps to take.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return text to the client as html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983859/how-to-return-text-to-the-client-as-html-page)

Comment: This one's been answered a few times here :)  Essentially you want to set some headers (specifically `content-disposition`, to tell the browser that the response is a file), write the file (or the string, rather) to the output, and close the output.  Good luck!

Comment: Combine these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884357/converting-dataset-datatable-to-csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/CSV";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + ".csv\"");
Response.Write(csvBuilder.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this answer will get you on the right track.

Make sure you set the contentType to the appropriate values for your file. 
Most likely  `response.ContentType = "text/plain";`

[Setting PDF file name dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259873/setting-pdf-file-name-dynamically)